# How copy constructor can be called with rvalue

Tags: c++11, copy-constructor, move-semantics, move-constructor, copy-elision

MWE:

```
struct A {
    A() {std::cout << "constructor" << std::endl; }
    A(const A& a) {std::cout << "copy constructor" << std::endl; }
    A(A&& a) {std::cout << "move constructor" << std::endl; }
};

int main() {
    A a1{};
    A a2{ a1 };
    A a3{ A{} };
    A a4{ std::move(a3) };
    return 0;
}
```

Output:

```
constructor
copy constructor
constructor
move constructor
```

for`a2` copy elision is used which is an optimization of the compiler and everything seems to be fine. When I comment out the move constructor however, copy constructor is called in place of move constructor. How can an rvalue be converted to a const lvalue reference? 
Output:

```
constructor
copy constructor
constructor
copy constructor
```

The program is compiled in `VS2017`.

Comment: *"How can an rvalue be converted to a const lvalue reference?"* Easily. Happens all the time. Why do you think this would be a problem? Well, "converted" is perhaps a wrong term: a const lvalue reference can be *bound* to a temporary object.

Comment: @IgorTandetnik, Yes you're right. It all happens due to `const`, didn't know this before. Maybe you can elaborate abit about the `bounding` as you mentioned in an answer. How does it work?

Comment: *"How can an rvalue be converted to a const lvalue reference?"* isn't this the basics of pass-by-copy optimization ?

Comment: @Jean-BaptisteYunès What is "pass-by-copy optimization"?

Comment: @curiousguy replacing `f(T v)` by `f(const T &v)` to eliminate the copy at each call.

Comment: @Jean-BaptisteYunès It isn't just an "optimization". It's inherently part of the concept of a copy constructor! If you don't have reference, good luck trying to define copy operations.

Comment: @curiousguy many languages don"t have such, pointers and functions are sufficient.

Comment: @Jean-BaptisteYunès They probably don't have operator overloading, user defined types with syntax similar to builtin types, flat structures (user defined types don't create indirections)...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

From en.cppreference.com:

> If both copy and move constructors are provided and no other
>   constructors are viable, overload resolution selects the move
>   constructor if the argument is an rvalue of the same type (an xvalue
>   such as the result of std::move or a prvalue such as a nameless
>   temporary (until C++17)), and selects the copy constructor if the
>   argument is an lvalue (named object or a function/operator returning
>   lvalue reference). If only the copy constructor is provided, all
>   argument categories select it (as long as it takes a reference to
>   const, since rvalues can bind to const references), which makes
>   copying the fallback for moving, when moving is unavailable.

This clearly says that rvalue can be bound to const lvalue reference.

Comment: Copy is the fallback. What about if copy & move are both available? Is move only used (starting 17) with explicit moves? I can confirm that nameless temporaries are handled through something else, though I can't generate a print message to tell me precisely what.